# symfony 3.4 "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known"

Tags: php, symfony, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds

Hello I'm trying to deploy my project in AWS EC2 and RDS. we developed our application using Symfony 3.4 Framework, my code in localhost is working fine with no issues.

After Hosted in AWS is not working. showing this error

```
 "message": "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known",
```

Postman Error message:

```
{
    "error": {
        "code": 500,
        "message": "Internal Server Error",
        "exception": [
            {
                "message": "An exception occurred in driver: SQLSTATE[HY000] [2002] php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: Name or service not known",
                "class": "Doctrine\\DBAL\\Exception\\ConnectionException",
                "trace": [
                    {
                        "namespace": "",
                        "short_class": "",
                        "class": "",
                        "type": "",
                        "function": "",
                        "file": "/var/www/html/ApartmentManagementScms/vendor/doctrine/dbal/lib/Doctrine/DBAL/Driver/AbstractMySQLDriver.php",
                        "line": 93,
                        "args": []
                    },

                ]
            },


        ]
    }
}
```

Apache Version in AWS:

```
Server version: Apache/2.4.18 (Ubuntu)
Server built:   2018-06-07T19:43:03
```

OS version:

```
    Distributor ID: Ubuntu
    Description:    Ubuntu 16.04.5 LTS
    Release:    16.04
    Codename:   xenial
```

Answer (score 2):

Double-check the host address you specified in the DSN. This error simply says that the name your specified for the mysql host can't be resolved.

Comment: Checked everything other pages are working fine, only login functionality is not working after JWT features added using this LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle [link](https://github.com/lexik/LexikJWTAuthenticationBundle)

Comment: I'm using Ubuntu I don't  is there any packages need to install, help me out from this.

Comment: @Kishor Do you use a centralized way of accessing the DB? (one single place in your code, where you init the connection)? If this is the only page where it fails, maybe this page is using a different piece of code to establish connection.

Answer (score 1):

Check your database configuration in .env file

DATABASE_URL=mysql://yourdbusername:yourdbpassword@127.0.0.1:3306/yourdbname